# *ngFor lado do cliente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou implementando um crud onde estou a utilizar o **ngFor** para iterar uma lista. Porém não sei como faze-lo no lado cliente. Creio que isso só será possível criando um componente no meu main.js . Porém não tenho certeza.

```js
var app = angular.module("crudlist", []); 
app.controller("MyCrud", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Músicas';    
    $scope.musicas =[];
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.nome = '';
    $scope.album = '';
    $scope.ano = '';
    $scope.object = {};
    $scope.add = function(){    
    $scope.object = {id: $scope.id ,nome:$scope.nome , album:$scope.album , ano:$scope.ano };
    $scope.musicas.push($scope.object);    
    $scope.id += 1;
  };
   $scope.delete = function(){
    $scope.musicas.pop();
  };
   $scope.clone =  function(id){   
   $scope.object = {id: $scope.id ,nome:$scope.musicas[id].nome , album:$scope.musicas[id].album , ano:$scope.musicas[id].ano };
   $scope.musicas.push($scope.object);   
   $scope.id += 1;  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="crudlist"ng-controller="MyCrud">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
<input type="text" ngModel="nome">
<input type="text" ngModel="album">
<input type="text" ngModel="ano">
<button ng-click="add()" >Adicionar música</button>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Albúm</th>
      <th>Ano</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of musicas" >
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.album}}</td>
      <td>{{item.ano}}</td>
      <button ngModel="delete()" >Delete</button>
      <button ngModel="clone(item.id)" >Clone</button>
    </tr>    
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Altere `*ngFor="let item of musicas"` para `ng-repeat="item in musicas"` ... Veja a [**documentação**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta havendo uma confusão, *ngFor* e *ngModel* estãopresente na versão 2+ do *Angular*. Já no *Angular 1* o correto é `ng-repeat` e `ng-model`:

```js
var app = angular.module("crudlist", []); 
app.controller("MyCrud", function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Músicas';    
  $scope.musicas =[];
  $scope.id = 0;
  $scope.nome = '';
  $scope.album = '';
  $scope.ano = '';
  $scope.object = {};
  $scope.add = function(){    
    $scope.object = {id: $scope.id ,nome:$scope.nome , album:$scope.album , ano:$scope.ano };
    $scope.musicas.push($scope.object);    
    $scope.id += 1;
  };
  $scope.delete = function(){
    $scope.musicas.pop();
  };
  $scope.clone =  function(id){   
    $scope.object = {id: $scope.id ,nome:$scope.musicas[id].nome , album:$scope.musicas[id].album , ano:$scope.musicas[id].ano };
    $scope.musicas.push($scope.object);   
    $scope.id += 1;  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="crudlist"ng-controller="MyCrud">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="nome">
<input type="text" ng-model="album">
<input type="text" ng-model="ano">
<button ng-click="add()" >Adicionar música</button>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Albúm</th>
      <th>Ano</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in musicas" >
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.album}}</td>
      <td>{{item.ano}}</td>
      <button ngModel="delete()" >Delete</button>
      <button ngModel="clone(item.id)" >Clone</button>
    </tr>    
  </table> 
</div>
```

#### Referências

- [AngularJS API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)
- [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs)